# Golang trimPrefix from string "\"

Tags: string, go

I've seen that golang have the function `func TrimPrefix(s, prefix string) string` which returns s without the provided leading prefix string.

My problem is that I have a string which start with the character "\" (for example "\foo"). When I try to use TrimPrefix I getting an error.

golang code:

```
var s = "\foo"
    s = strings.TrimPrefix(s, "\")
    fmt.Print(s)
```

error:

```
./prog.go:10:32: newline in string
./prog.go:10:32: syntax error: unexpected newline, expecting comma or )
```

I have seen that it is due to golang understang "\" as the scape character. Do you know if ther is any golang option I can use in order to make golang understand that I don't want to use "\" as the escape character?

Comment: Just use "\\", since the first slash escapes the second one.

Comment: notice how your program prints and is highlighted. Its abnormally red for the last line because the literal is not terminated due to that backslash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`"\"` is not a valid Go string literal. What you get is a compile-time error. In [interpreted string literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) backslash `\` is a special character.

If you want the string to contain a backslash character, you have to use the sequence `\\`:

```
var s = "\\foo"
s = strings.TrimPrefix(s, "\\")
```

Which will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NlLPtUE23UH)):

```
foo
```

Another option is to use raw string literals where the backslash is not special:

```
var s = `\foo`
s = strings.TrimPrefix(s, `\`)
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NFJtbloOb1P).

Answer (score 1):

if you only want to trim the prefix which is a specific prefix( like "\" is a prefix with length of 1 ), you can use slice function as :`str[len(prefix):]`.

Just because it is a prefix -- head of a string and a length-known prefix.

Ignore my post if you only want to know the use of `TrimPrefix`.  :D